# Jquery array submit

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, arrays

I have a page where there are 117 input fields. What i want is to submit them via Jquery ajax. What i am thinking is to make an array and send them by this way. I would like to ask how is it possible to **take all inputs** and then to **put them in an array** and then **retrieve them from the php file** (for example, should i do explode,or for each..etc??) 
The input fields are not in a form (just in div with id = "config")
Thanks.

Comment: yes but how to find all inputs,make an array,and then explode the array?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1184624/serialize-form-to-json-with-jquery then on the PHP side: json_decode($array)

Answer (score 2):

Stringify the data on the client side into JSON(there is a stringifier available [here](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/blob/master/json2.js)). Then, on the server-side use [`json_decode($json_str)`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php).

Another option is to put all those input fields into an actual form and then use jQuery's [`serialize()`](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/) (which would actually be a whole lot easier).

Answer (score 2):

Why not use [`.serialize()`](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/), along with an ajax POST?  In PHP, they will all be accessible via the [`$_POST`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php) 'superglobal' array.